# C# Client Server Problem after trying as Win Forms App instead of pure console

Tags: c#, sockets, server, tcp, client

**Server:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace Client_SuperChat
{
    public partial class Superchat_Client : Form
    {
        public Superchat_Client()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        public void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.166");
            int port = 123;
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(ip, port);
            Console.WriteLine("client connected!!");
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            Thread thread = new Thread(o => ReceiveData((TcpClient)o));

            thread.Start(client);

            string s;
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((s = Console.ReadLine())))
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
                ns.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
            thread.Join();
            ns.Close();
            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("disconnect from server!!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public void ReceiveData(TcpClient client)
        {
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[1024];
            int byte_count;

            while ((byte_count = ns.Read(receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytes.Length)) > 0)
            {
                Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, byte_count));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace test_Clie
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.166");
            int port = 123;
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(ip, port);
            Console.WriteLine("client connected!!");
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();           //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<- here I get the error
            Thread thread = new Thread(o => ReceiveData((TcpClient)o));

            thread.Start(client);

            string s;
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((s = Console.ReadLine())))
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
                ns.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
            thread.Join();
            ns.Close();
            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("disconnect from server!!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void ReceiveData(TcpClient client)
        {
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[1024];
            int byte_count;

            while ((byte_count = ns.Read(receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytes.Length)) > 0)
            {
                Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, byte_count));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error in this line **NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();**
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.dll
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll"
that the procedure isnt allowed for non connected sockets

**Plain Version in console worked...
Client_Console:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace test_Clie
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.166");
            int port = 5000;
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(ip, port);
            Console.WriteLine("client connected!!");
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            Thread thread = new Thread(o => ReceiveData((TcpClient)o));

            thread.Start(client);

            string s;
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty((s = Console.ReadLine())))
            {
                byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
                ns.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }

            client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
            thread.Join();
            ns.Close();
            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("disconnect from server!!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void ReceiveData(TcpClient client)
        {
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
            byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[1024];
            int byte_count;

            while ((byte_count = ns.Read(receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytes.Length)) > 0)
            {
                Console.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes, 0, byte_count));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Server_Console**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace testServ
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly object _lock = new object();
        static readonly Dictionary<int, TcpClient> list_clients = new Dictionary<int, TcpClient>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count = 1;

            TcpListener ServerSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 5000);
            ServerSocket.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                lock (_lock) list_clients.Add(count, client);
                Console.WriteLine("Someone connected!!");

                Thread t = new Thread(handle_clients);
                t.Start(count);
                count++;
            }
        }

        public static void handle_clients(object o)
        {
            int id = (int)o;
            TcpClient client;

            lock (_lock) client = list_clients[id];

            while (true)
            {
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int byte_count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                if (byte_count == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, byte_count);
                broadcast(data);
                Console.WriteLine(data);
            }

            lock (_lock) list_clients.Remove(id);
            client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            client.Close();
        }

        public static void broadcast(string data)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data + Environment.NewLine);

            lock (_lock)
            {
                foreach (TcpClient c in list_clients.Values)
                {
                    NetworkStream stream = c.GetStream();

                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your connection is not completing.  Which line is failing?  The server has to start before the Client.  Are you getting the following message "client connected!!".  You can only have one connection with same three parameters 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number.  I think the client is closing the connection after one message.

Comment: the lower version as a console standalone works somewhat fine, just terminates after 1 client is closed, thats not a problem for now, but when i try to do it as a windows form app the client doesnt even start and i get the described error :(